# how can I create a search box like Facebook's or WhatsApp's? (Mobile)

Tags: angularjs, css, user-interface, user-experience

Is there a way to do that manually ? I was trying to use `Ionic Framework`, they had an `attribute` for that but is deprecated now.

By Facebook's/WhatsApp's search box I mean:

1 - Hidden at first sigh

2 - If you want to see it you have to pull down

3 - Once you focus on it, it extends up to the top of the screen and overlaps the header

4 - Has a button which is an X to delete the content of the search box and other button named "Cancel" to close the search box.

Pretty sure everyone has notice that behavior already.

So, what are the techniques to implement it ?

I am using Angular so I do not know if there is a way to do a Directive, or just with css ? what are your suggestions ?

[image]
[image]

[something like this](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/pvpPxz)

Comment: What search box ..... do you mind posting a link ?

Comment: @Federico take a look at your Facebooks Messenger or the whatsapps search box. I just edited my question. sorry

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer facebook messenger/whatsapp search box on which platform ? try to add some screenshots

Comment: @Shekhar please see my update and the link I just added, and is for mobile

Comment: ahhh ok IPhone. So you would like to impalement it in your iPhone App. I am not proficient at it but I am pretty sure that in the iOS API there is a specific module for it.

Comment: @Federico my app is an Hybrid, I am working with Ionic Framework, so the solution could be with AngularJS or something similar. The same is going to be use on iPhone and Android.

Comment: I am not so familiar with it... sorry. I know how to work it out with Css & Js.

Comment: @Federico yes my friend. that's what I need, with CSS and JS. Can you give me a hand with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be too time consuming for me to realize the all thing. but is not so difficoult if you are familiar with " transitions " in css3.

here is a "lite version"

```js
var searchbox={
 topPos_open:0, topPos_close:-50, isOpen:false,
 open:function(){
     var box=document.getElementById("searchbox");
     box.style.top=this.topPos_open+"px";
        document.getElementById("searchfield").focus();
        this.isOpen=true;
 },
 close:function(){
     var box=document.getElementById("searchbox");
     box.style.top=this.topPos_close+"px";
     this.isOpen=false;
 },
 pop:function(){
     !this.isOpen?this.open():this.close();
 },
 clear:function(){
  document.getElementById("searchfield").value="";
 }
}
```

```css
#searchbox{position:fixed; top:-50px; left:0px; width:100%; height:60px; background-color:rgba(135, 206, 235, 1); -webkit-transition:top 0.5s ease 0s; -moz-transition:top 0.5s ease 0s; transition:top 0.5s ease 0s;}
#searchbox input{border:0px none; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; padding:0px; width:80%; font-size:20px;}
#searchbox #input{float:left; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); border:1px solid #dddddd; border-radius:20px; margin:5px; padding:5px; width:70%; min-width:250px;}
#searchbox #close{float:right; padding:10px:}
#searchbox button{border:0px none; background-color:transparent; font-size:20px; cursor:pointer;}
#searchbox #dots{clear:both; text-align:center; font-size:25px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="searchbox">
    <div id="input">
      <input type="text" id="searchfield" value="">
      <button type="button" onclick="searchbox.clear()">
        X
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="close">
      <button type="button" onclick="searchbox.close()">
        Cancel
      </button></div>
    <div id="dots" onclick="searchbox.pop()">
      ......
    </div>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Click the dots
```